# Is it possible to convert a JSON file filled with XPath back to an XML file?

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xpath

I have a JSON file with all XPaths inside. I'm wondering if there's a way to convert that into an XML file by using some modules very conveniently, like lxml?

Currently, I'm using Regex to turn that into the XML structure - not sure if this is a good practice...Below is part of the XPath example:

```
//*[local-name()='validator' or local-name()='compare' or local-name()='custom' or local-name()='required' or local-name()='regular']/@*[name()='text' or name()='errormessage']|//email-topic/@name|//*[local-name()='column' or local-name()='hyperlink' or local-name()='button' or local-name()='bound']/*[name()='footer' or name()='header']|
```

I would like to make it look like:
    `<validator>`
    `<compare>`
    `<custom>`
    ...
    `<bound footer="">`
    `<bount header="">`

By the way, please let me know if I interpret the XPath wrong. Not very familiar with this concept.
If you have any ideas, please let me know. I'll do more research myself as well! Thank you!

Comment: It will be great if you post sample json as well as provide more context on application type, programming language for conversion etc then it will be easy for people to provide their inputs.

Comment: It seems possible to do it if the XPath expressions follow some very strict rules, and impossible otherwise. So we need to see the XPath expressions! As for the technical approach, I would personally use XSLT 2.0 with recursive grouping to find sets of XPath expressions having a common prefix.

Comment: Hi, @MichaelKay, I've made some changes in my question and added an example. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, @PankajKapare I've added an example in my question. Hope it helps! Thank you very much!

Comment: I can't see how one could derive an XML structure from your sample XPath, sorry. It's very under-specified. And the thing you want to make it look like isn't XML, there are no end tags.

Comment: @michaelKay Yep, that's right! Sorry for making it vague. We only need the opening tags to be imported into our system so the system recognize all the tags from the original XMLs. Right now, I haven't found any other way rather than use Regex to grab the tags and attributes. So I guess there's no other way of doing it other than that. Thank you veyr much anyway!  :)